Borland C++Builder 6 patched application gives "EAccessViolation" every time I restart the computer
I have a Borland C++Builder 6 application which I have added some imports using CFF Explorer, which creates a new section just in case I overwrite the IAT table with patched codes.
There is no antivirus, and all the security features, like the exploit protections, are turned off.
The application is patched with codes which read the command line arguments.
Now, every time I restart the computer the application, it gives the following error:

EAccessViolation

When I check my code it is shown as:
004A4090  60                pushad        
004A4091  9C                pushfd        
004A4092  68 B0424A00       push postquitmessage.4A42B0    
004A4097  E8 D4DCED75       call shell32.76381D70  // THIS SHOULD BE SHOWN AS call <kernel32.GetCommandLineW>
004A409C  50                push eax                
004A409D  E8 8E627375       call 75BDA330          // THIS SHOULD BE SHOWN AS call <shcore.CommandLineToArgvW> 
004A40A2  A3 D6434A00       mov dword ptr ds:[4A43D6],eax      
004A40A7  833D D6434A00 00  cmp dword ptr ds:[4A43D6],0   
004A40AE  0F84 DF000000     je <postquitmessage.loc_40187A>    
004A40B4  833D B0424A00 04  cmp dword ptr ds:[4A42B0],4    
004A40BB  0F8E D2000000     jle <postquitmessage.loc_40187A>   
004A40C1  6A 00             push 0         
004A40C3  6A 00             push 0         
004A40C5  6A 00             push 0         
004A40C7  6A 00             push 0         
004A40C9  6A FF             push FFFFFFFF      
004A40CB  8B15 D6434A00     mov edx,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]      
004A40D1  FF72 04           push dword ptr ds:[edx+4]     
004A40D4  6A 00             push 0         
004A40D6  6A 00             push 0         
004A40D8  E8 139FED75       call shell32.7637DFF0  // THIS SHOULD BE SHOWN AS call <kernel32.WideCharToMultiByte>
004A40DD  A3 07454A00       mov dword ptr ds:[4A4507],eax      
004A40E2  FF35 07454A00     push dword ptr ds:[4A4507]     
004A40E8  E8 9BD31532       call <cc3260mt.@$bnwa$qui>  // ADDED IMPORT WHICH IS SHOWN RIGHTLY
004A40ED  59                pop ecx       
004A40EE  A3 DC454A00       mov dword ptr ds:[4A45DC],eax      
004A40F3  6A 00             push 0         
004A40F5  6A 00             push 0         
004A40F7  FF35 07454A00     push dword ptr ds:[4A4507]     
004A40FD  FF35 DC454A00     push dword ptr ds:[4A45DC]     
004A4103  6A FF             push FFFFFFFF      
004A4105  8B0D D6434A00     mov ecx,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]     
004A410B  FF71 04           push dword ptr ds:[ecx+4]     
004A410E  6A 00             push 0         
004A4110  6A 00             push 0         
004A4112  E8 D99EED75       call shell32.7637DFF0  // THIS SHOULD BE SHOWN AS call <kernel32.WideCharToMultiByte>
004A4117  A1 D6434A00       mov eax,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]     
004A411C  FF70 08           push dword ptr ds:[eax+8]      
004A411F  E8 24231D32       call <cc3260mt.__wtoi>     
004A4124  59                pop ecx        
004A4125  A3 70464A00       mov dword ptr ds:[4A4670],eax     
004A412A  8B15 D6434A00     mov edx,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]      
004A4130  FF72 0C           push dword ptr ds:[edx+C]      
004A4133  E8 10231D32       call <cc3260mt.__wtoi>     
etc. etc.

This is how it is shown after re-applying the patch, and then it works:
004A4090  60                 pushad        
004A4091  9C                 pushfd        
004A4092  68 B0424A00        push postquitmessage.4A42B0    
004A4097  E8 74DFDA74        call <kernel32.GetCommandLineW>   
004A409C  50                 push eax               004A409D  E8 1EF44875        call <shcore.CommandLineToArgvW>   
004A40A2  A3 D6434A00        mov dword ptr ds:[4A43D6],eax      
004A40A7  833D D6434A00 00   cmp dword ptr ds:[4A43D6],0    
004A40AE  0F84 DF000000      je <postquitmessage.loc_40187A>   
004A40B4  833D B0424A00 04   cmp dword ptr ds:[4A42B0],4   
004A40BB  0F8E D2000000      jle <postquitmessage.loc_40187A>  
004A40C1  6A 00              push 0         
004A40C3  6A 00              push 0         
004A40C5  6A 00              push 0         
004A40C7  6A 00              push 0         
004A40C9  6A FF              push FFFFFFFF      
004A40CB  8B15 D6434A00      mov edx,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]      
004A40D1  FF72 04            push dword ptr ds:[edx+4]     
004A40D4  6A 00              push 0        
004A40D6  6A 00              push 0         
004A40D8  E8 B3A1DA74        call <kernel32.WideCharToMultiByte>    
004A40DD  A3 07454A00        mov dword ptr ds:[4A4507],eax      
004A40E2  FF35 07454A00      push dword ptr ds:[4A4507]     
004A40E8  E8 9BD31532        call <cc3260mt.@$bnwa$qui>     
004A40ED  59                 pop ecx        
004A40EE  A3 DC454A00        mov dword ptr ds:[4A45DC],eax   
004A40F3  6A 00              push 0         
004A40F5  6A 00              push 0         
004A40F7  FF35 07454A00      push dword ptr ds:[4A4507]    
004A40FD  FF35 DC454A00      push dword ptr ds:[4A45DC]     
004A4103  6A FF              push FFFFFFFF      
004A4105  8B0D D6434A00      mov ecx,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]      
004A410B  FF71 04            push dword ptr ds:[ecx+4]     
004A410E  6A 00              push 0        
004A4110  6A 00              push 0        
004A4112  E8 79A1DA74        call <kernel32.WideCharToMultiByte>   
004A4117  A1 D6434A00        mov eax,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]      
004A411C  FF70 08            push dword ptr ds:[eax+8]      
004A411F  E8 24231D32        call <cc3260mt.__wtoi>     
004A4124  59                 pop ecx        
004A4125  A3 70464A00        mov dword ptr ds:[4A4670],eax      
004A412A  8B15 D6434A00      mov edx,dword ptr ds:[4A43D6]      
004A4130  FF72 0C            push dword ptr ds:[edx+C]      
004A4133  E8 10231D32        call <cc3260mt.__wtoi>    
etc. etc.

So, to sum-up, at the beginning when added imports and patched, it works, but every time I restart the computer it gives EAccessViolation and I have to re-apply the patches to get it working again.
Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Why are you patching the exe to begin with? How exactly are you applying the patches, and what are they actually doing? If I had to guess, the patch is probably not taking Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) into account.  The OS randomizes the base address of system DLLs (amongst other things) every time it reboots.

Was the app installed with an installer (as opposed to just copied in place)? If so, it could be that Windows is detecting that something has changed and is "repairing" it at boot-up by copying it from a shadow backup area. I know Windows can do that for some of its own files at least.

just read carefully, as I said every security features is turned off, every single one. Also not every import is wrong: 004A40E8  E8 9BD31532       call <cc3260mt.@$bnwa$qui>  // ADDED IMPORT WHICH IS SHOWN RIGHTLY
and no installer.
